# how to update template or campaign status to draft or programmed in mailjet

Tags: php, email, mailjet

I use mailjet in my php program to send mails to my receivers. I use templates (or known as campaigns) as content of my mail. My code is ..

```
$ch         =   curl_init();
$content    =   "https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/newsletter/3594662/send";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$content);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "myapi:mypassword");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
$server_output1 = curl_exec ($ch);
# Close curl process
curl_close ($ch);
```

Note: I am hardcoding the template id (id:3594662) in my program.
And the problem is ..
Once i sent a mail , that template's status will change to "sent".
So if i send another mail using the same template(id:3594662) i will get error message like this:

```
"errmessage": "Newsletter has to be in status draft or programmed",
"statuscode": "400
```

Please help me how to update the status of template to "draft or programmed"..
Advance Thanks for the replies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm leading Developers Relations at Mailjet. Thanks for having chosen us to power your email!

As far as I see, there is a confusion about the role of the newsletter API resource. This resource represents a single newsletter / campaign object in the system, not a re-usable template as you're expecting. This is a feature we're working on and which will be live in few weeks from now.

In your case, you will need to re-create the newsletter from scratch, following our [API guide](http://dev.mailjet.com/guides/?php#send-marketing-campaigns), like you're already doing I guess.

Sorry about the inconvenience. Please remain confident that we're working on improving this ASAP.

Hope this helps!

Comment: $postfields = array('Status' => '0','EditMode' => 'tool');

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.mailjet.com/v3/REST/newsletter?DuplicateFrom=108');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'apikey:seckey');

this code is for campaign duplication.I can duplicate th campaign bt its content is null

Comment: That's correct that the duplication only duplicates the object itself (meta information) but not its content. Please issue a POST request on /newsletter/:new_id/detailcontent with the content you want.